# How to add comma separated String values to List model(ex:List<GridModel)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a scenario in which I have to add comma separated string values to List model object. I am attaching controller method in which comma separated values are received from jquery code(js file). Please help.

### Code:-

```
public void update_session(string accntname, string bu, string salesop, string isdormant)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(accntname);/* receive values like BSNL,TATA in this accnt name*/
            List<GridModel> lgm = new List<GridModel>();
            string[] values = accntname.Split(',');

            string[] values1 = bu.Split(',');

            string[] values2 = salesop.Split(',');

            string[] values3= salesop.Split(',');



        }
```

### Model calss:-

```
public class GridModel
    {
        public string accntname{get;set;}
        public string BU{get;set;}
        public int salesop { get; set; }
        public bool isdormant { get; set; }

    }
```

I need to add values as shown below to the List model object by making in a loop

lgm.add(new GridModel{accntname=accntname,BU=bu,salesop=salesop,isdormant=isdormant})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like that?

```
for(int i = 0; i < values.Length; i++)
{
    lgm.Add(new GridModel{accntname = values[i], BU = values1[i], ... };
}
```

Additionally, you should implement a Constructor for the GridModel, would make your life a bit easier.